# Why does this self addition equal 0?

Tags: java, addition

Curious about how fast self addition would grow, I wrote a quick little loop in Java to see:

```
int count = 1;
while(true){
    System.out.println(count);
    count += count;
}
```

The output was unexpected:

```
0
0
0
0
0
...
```

Why is this? `count` is initialized to 1, so the inner addition should be doing `count + count` or `1 + 1`. Why is the result 0?

Comment: Put a short `Thread.sleep` between loop iterations.

Comment: Imagine that there is a `int x` value which when you do `x+=x` overflows integer to `0`. What would be your results after it?

Comment: what would that do @SotiriosDelimanolis

Comment: Just do it, make it like 1 second.

Comment: Oh, I see, overflows too quickly, so that when `count` is at `int max`, the next value will cause the addition to be `0`? @SotiriosDelimanolis

Comment: "when count is at int max" not quite, but you are close: `...`->`1073741824` -> `-2147483648` -> `0`->`0`->`...`

Comment: You could also just put `while(count > 0)` that way you dont keep zeros spamming your console. `while(true)` with no `break` tends to not be the greatest idea. Anyway it will take ~30 iterations before you overflow.

Comment: right, 31, corresponding to the number of bits, since this addition is essentially exponents of 2. Makes sense now @ug_

Comment: First you need to see the complete output the answer is right there.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The output you've posted is the trailing lines of the output, not the first 30-31 lines. It goes so fast that after the first 31 iterations it goes beyond `INT MAX` and the addition results in 0. Remember that a signed integer has a max value of `2^31`, or 4 bytes with a sign bit.

Instead of `while(true) {` try `while(count>0) {`, you will get to see the first few iterations when it wasn't 0.

Comment: Yea, makes sense. The result should go to 0 on the 32nd iteration, corresponding to the number of bits in a signed integer. Thanks.